# How to use feTurbulence and feDisplacementMap with `svg.filter.js`?

Tags: svg, svg-filters, svg.js

This SVG filter:

```
<filter id="xkcdify" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="-5" y="-5" width="100%" height="100%">
  <feTurbulence 
      type="fractalNoise" baseFrequency="0.05" result="noise" 
  />
  <feDisplacementMap 
      scale="5" xChannelSelector="R" yChannelSelector="G" 
      in="SourceGraphic" in2="noise" 
  />
</filter>
```

is used by the [Chart XKCD package](https://timqian.com/chart.xkcd/example.html), to apply a displacement map to SVG data.

I am trying to determine how to make similar filters using [`svg.filter.js`](https://github.com/svgdotjs/svg.filter.js), but what I have is not working:

```
    g.filterWith(add =>
      add
        .turbulence(0.05, 1, 0, "stitch", "fractalNoise")
        .displacementMap(add.SourceGraphic, 5, "R", "G")
    );
```

The above code generates this filter:

```
<filter id="SvgjsFilter1029">
  <feTurbulence 
    id="SvgjsFeTurbulence1027" 
    in="SourceGraphic"
    result="SvgjsFeTurbulence1027"  
    type="fractalNoise" stitchTiles="stitch" seed="115" 
    numOctaves="1" baseFrequency="0.05" 
  />
  <feDisplacementMap 
    id="SvgjsFeDisplacementMap1028" 
    in="SvgjsFeTurbulence1027" 
    result="SvgjsFeDisplacementMap1028"
    yChannelSelector="G" xChannelSelector="R" scale="5" 
  />
</filter>
```

Which does not do what I want.

It takes my input:

[image]

and turns it into this:

[image]

My goal is to generate a filter like the first one, which when applied to the input gives this:

[image]

Is there a way to do this with `svg.filter.js`?

Comment: you can have a look here for an animated example: https://codepen.io/fuzzyma/pen/XoMPEp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

- `add.SourceGraphic` should be `add.$source` (there are plenty of examples in the [readme](https://github.com/svgdotjs/svg.filter.js/blob/master/README.md#displacementmap)).
- To get `in`/`in2` in the right order for the `feDisplacementMap`, you need to create your filters in separate steps (no chaining).

```js
rect.filterWith(add => {
    var noise = add.turbulence(0.05, 1, 0, "stitch", "fractalNoise");
    add.displacementMap(add.$source, noise, 5, "R", "G");
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yxobe2dp/